# Split array of dates into multiple arrays

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

For example, i have array with some dates

2016-11-11T12:13:14.120Z

2016-11-12T12:13:14.120Z

2016-11-13T12:13:14.120Z

2016-12-10T12:12:14.120Z

2016-12-10T12:13:14.120Z

2016-12-10T15:13:14.120Z

2016-12-11T12:13:14.120Z

2017-01-11T12:13:14.120Z

i need to achieve something like this :

```
[[2016-11-11T12:13:14.120Z, 2016-11-12T12:13:14.120Z], [2016-11-13T12:13:14.120Z], [2016-12-10T12:12:14.120Z,2016-12-10T12:13:14.120Z,2016-12-10T15:13:14.120Z, 2016-12-11T12:13:14.120Z], [2017-01-11T12:13:14.120Z]]
```

if difference between first and n+1 date is less then 24h this dates must be in array, else - create next array and so on.

I can write only something like that

```
   int step = 24;
    int currentPos = 0;

 ArrayList<ArrayList<Item>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Item> currentArray = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            Item item = items.get(currentPos);
            for (int j = 0; j < items.size(); j++) {
                int tmp = currentPos + 1;
                if (DateUtils.getDifferenceInHours(item.getEndDate(), items.get(tmp).getEndDate()) <= step) {
                    currentArray.add(items.get(tmp));
                    currentPos++;
                } else {
                    currentArray.add(item);
                    result.add(currentArray);
                    currentArray = new ArrayList<>();
                    currentPos++;
                    break;
                }

            }
    }
```

But i have indexOutOfBoundsException
Please, help!

Comment: What have you done so far? Show your code.

Comment: @KNeerajLal i have done date comparing, but i cant write a correct loop to achieve the correct result

Comment: Show your code and try to explain what the problem is.

Comment: @KNeerajLal i have edited my question

Comment: Can I give you an example with integers? Can you adapt it for dates?

Comment: @KNeerajLal i think yes, i can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simplified example with integers.I Used a `Set` to remove the duplicates from the result.

Try this,

```
// Create sample ArrayList. Don't do this in your actual code.
ArrayList<Integer> items = new ArrayList<Integer>() {
    {
        add(1);
        add(2);
        add(3);
        add(2);
        add(3);
        add(2);                
        add(4);                
    }
};

int step = 24;
Set<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new HashSet<>();       

for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    Integer item1 = items.get(i);
    ArrayList<Integer> currentArray = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < items.size(); j++) {
        Integer item2 = items.get(j);
        if (item1 == item2) { // This is where you need to find the difference of dates
            currentArray.add(item1);
        }
    }
    result.add(currentArray);
}

System.out.println(result);
```

Output,

```
[[4], [1], [3, 3], [2, 2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        for (int item  : items) {
        for (int j = 0; j < items.size(); j++) {
            int tmp = currentPos + 1;
            if (DateUtils.getDifferenceInHours(item.getEndDate(), items.get(tmp).getEndDate()) <= step) {
                currentArray.add(items.get(tmp));
                currentPos++;
            } else {
                currentArray.add(item);
                result.add(currentArray);
                currentArray = new ArrayList<>();
                currentPos++;
                break;
            }

        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Item item = items.get(currentPos); have index out of bounds exception on this line

Comment: last item of array missed

Comment: Please try this !

Comment: now i have indexOutOfBounds exception on "DateUtils.getDifferenceInHours" line :)